# What does it mean that a view is contained in a container when the container is a UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

There are 2 type of classes that satisfy UIAppearanceContainer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/UIAppearanceContainer_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearanceContainer

UIView
UIViewController

Say we do:

```
[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:@[[UYLRotatingViewController class]]];
```

How does iOS know whether a UIButton is in UYLRotatingViewController?

Does it mean that it's in the view of UYLRotatingViewController?

Comment: you mean subview of UYLRotatingViewController.view?

Answer (score 0):

When the given `UIButton` is given a superview (`[myView addSubview:button]`), UIKit most likely calls `[[button superview] class]`, and compares this class with any conditional appearance customisations that it may have. In other words, if UIKit finds that `[[button superview] class]` is equal to `[UYLRotatingViewController class]`, it applies the appearance customisations that you have passed to this proxy object.